# Laravel Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'cm_firebase_token'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I I'm trying to edit existing project i added some `php artisan migrations` and when im trying to `php artisan migrate` or `php artisan schema:dump` it is keep showing this error message i tried `composer update` and `composer require doctrine/dbal` and also my `.env` looks like this

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:/NC6CNBiDJb2vV4fRviEsMqy5gKbePRgk44JGkZFAYY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_MODE=dev

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=phpmyadmin
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
SOFTWARE_ID=MzM1NzE3NTA=
BUYER_USERNAME=tt
PURCHASE_CODE=fsgf
```

error shows like this in the terminal please anyone suggest me to solve this issue

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[42S21]:  Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'cm_firebase_token'(SQL: alter table `users` add `cm_firebase_token` varchar(191) null)

  at C:\Users\Crazymhegde\Downloads\Admin Install\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }

  1   C:\Users\Crazymhegde\Downloads\Admin Install\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'cm_firebase_token'")

  2   C:\Users\Crazymhegde\Downloads\Admin Install\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

and my code which this error shows to is here i added everything it required

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddCmFirebaseTokenColumnToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('cm_firebase_token')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('cm_firebase_token');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error tells you: the column you try to create already exists

Comment: if i delete or remove the this migration is it works fine / is it any problem

Comment: You may have ran the migration before and didn't do a `php artisan migrate:rollback` to undo the change, though the migrations table seems to be out of sync now so do drop the column manually

Answer (score 0):

Column name `cm_firebase_token` alredy exist in table. It looks like you created the migration after you manually added the column into table.

Just copy the migration file name and insert it into `migrations` table.

Comment: Inputting manually in the migrations table is not good, as adding columns manually is. Its better to rollback the migration.

Comment: Is it possible to rollback migration which is not present in `migrations` table?

Answer (score 0):

you shoould use php artisan migrate:fresh command to renew your database

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer